# How to create an interface for var containing arrays of objects with type safety?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I haven't used TS in some time, and forgot how to properly set a type for this variable. I think it would be best to create an interface - something like ShirtDescription which would contain brand and serial defined as strings. But then how would I go about including the properties polo and brand?

```
const shirts = {
  polo: [
    { brand: "some brand", serial: "some serial" },
    { brand: "some brand", serial: "some serial" },
  ],
  sleeveless: [
    { brand: "some brand", serial: "some serial" },
    { brand: "some brand", serial: "some serial" },
  ],
};
```

What type would I set for 'shirts' here once the interfaces are created?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility would be:

```js
interface Shirt {
  brand: string;
  serial: string;
}

type ShirtType = "polo" | "sleeveless"

const shirts: Record<ShirtType, Shirt[]> = {
  polo: [
    { brand: "some brand", serial: "some serial" },
    { brand: "some brand", serial: "some serial" },
  ],
  sleeveless: [
    { brand: "some brand", serial: "some serial" },
    { brand: "some brand", serial: "some serial" },
  ],
};
```